# Can women wear golden chains?

Tags: halal-haram, women, adornments

I know that men should not wear golden materials. Few days before, I had heard that ladies also should not wear golden chains. Please clarify my doubts with proof.

Comment: Only men shouldn't wear gold.

Comment: Gold and silk is permitted to women but not men.

Answer (score 6):

Assalamu Alaikum,

Only women can wear the golden jewelry. It's Haram for men.

Because Ali bin Abi Talib said:

> أَخَذَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ ***حَرِيرًا*** بِشِمَالِهِ
>   ***وَذَهَبًا*** بِيَمِينِهِ ثُمَّ رَفَعَ بِهِمَا يَدَيْهِ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏
>   **إِنَّ هَذَيْنِ حَرَامٌ عَلَى ذُكُورِ أُمَّتِي حِلٌّ لإِنَاثِهِمْ** ‏"‏
>
> The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) took hold of some ***silk*** in his left hand
>   and some ***gold*** in his right, then he raised his hands and said:
>   ‘**These two are forbidden for the males of my nation, and permitted
>   to the females**.’
>   [Sunnah ibn majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1337270)

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 3):

According to Quran there is no prohibition in women wearing Gold. But you will find hadiths supporting and opposing it.

Supporting Hadiths

> “The Messenger of Allah  took hold of some silk in his left hand and
>   some gold in his right, then he raised his hands and said: ‘These two
>   are forbidden for the males of my nation, and permitted to the
>   females.’”
>
> Ibn Majah
>   **Vol. 1, Book 32, Hadith 3595**
>
> Narated By 'Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin : The Prophet (pbuh) got some
>   ornaments presented by Negus as a gift to him. They contained a gold
>   ring with an Abyssinian stone. The Apostle of Allah (pbuh) turning his
>   attention from it took it by means of a stick or his finger, then
>   called Umamah, daughter of Abu al-'As and daughter of his daughter
>   Zaynab, and said: Wear it, my dear daughter.
>
> **Abu Dawud Book 029,**
>   **Hadith Number 4223.**

Opposing Hadiths

> Narated By A sister of Hudhayfah : The Prophet (pbuh) said: You women
>   folk, have in silver something with which you adorn yourselves. I
>   assure you that any woman of you who adorns herself with gold which
>   she displays will be punished for it.
>
> **Abu Dawud Book 029, Hadith Number 4225.**
>
> Narated By Asma', daughter of Yazid : The Prophet (pbuh) said: Any
>   woman who wears a gold necklace will have a similar one of fire put on
>   her neck on the Day of Resurrection, and any woman who puts a gold
>   earring in her ear will have a similar one of fire put in her ear on
>   the Day of Resurrection.
>
> **Abu Dawud Book 029, Hadith Number 4226.**

If you read the Bible you will find opposing view

> **1 Timothy 2:9** In like manner also, that women adorn themselves in modest apparel, with shamefacedness and sobriety; not with broided
>   hair, or gold, or pearls, or costly array;

No one has the right to make a lawful  thing unlawful and vice versa .
Quran 16:116 , 7:32 , 66:1-2.

Hope you find the answer